# how to close specific serial port in C++ MFC smart device application?

Tags: c++, mfc, smart-device

how to close specific serial port in C++ MFC smart device application?

how to check if a port is open?

and how to close it?

i am using this "
ex: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms881795.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close handle that you have got from `CreateFile` you should use [`CloseHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms959878.aspx) function.